# Использование RichTextFX

Tags: java, javafx

У меня есть консоль, которая реализована на `TextFlow`. В ней меняется цвет, в зависимости от типа сообщения (ERROR - red, WARNING - yellow и тд).

Появилась необходимость выделения и копирования сообщений оттуда. Искал способы реализации данной задачи и чаще всего встречал `RichTextFX`, но мне не понятно его использование. Вот как выглядит моя консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чем из `RichTextFX` можно заменить мою реализацию в `TextFlow`?

И если есть какой-то туториал по `RichTextFX` кроме того что на GitHub - буду рад его получить!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчет другого руководства, кроме указанного на `github`, я не знаю. Но указанного там достаточно для вашей задачи:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.InlineCssTextArea;

import java.util.Random;

public class Main extends Application {

    private static final String ERROR_STYLE = "-fx-fill: red;";
    private static final String WARN_STYLE = "-fx-fill: blue;";

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        final InlineCssTextArea inlineCssTextArea = new InlineCssTextArea();
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(inlineCssTextArea));
        primaryStage.show();

        // Этот сделан для демонстрации
        // Будут выведены 30 сообщение, тип сообщения (WARN, ERROR) определяется произвольно
        new Thread(() -> {
            Random random = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                // Выбрали стиль
                final String style = random.nextBoolean() ? ERROR_STYLE : WARN_STYLE;
                // Сгенирировали сообщение
                final String message = String.valueOf(i).concat("\n");
                Platform.runLater(() -> {
                    // получаем границы нового сообещения
                    int from = inlineCssTextArea.getLength();
                    int to = from + message.length();
                    // добавили сообещние
                    inlineCssTextArea.appendText(message);
                    // указали для него стиль
                    inlineCssTextArea.setStyle(from, to, style);
                });
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) { /* NOP */ }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

и соответственно

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
        <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
```