# Выбор способа вывода текста для консоли приложения

Tags: java, javafx

Есть консоль, которая реализована с помощью `TextFlow`, там цветные сообщения (если ошибка - красное, предупреждение - желтое и тд). `TextFlow` не дает выделять сообщение, а мне это нужно для реализации будущих задач. Подскажите, пожалуйста, чем я могу воспользоваться (в пределах JavaFX).

`RichTextFX` хотелось бы избежать. Если избежать никак - хотелось бы получить хоть какую-то документацию по `RichTextFX`, тк информация на официальном git слишком скудна.

Answer (score 0):

В `JavaFX` нет родных компонентов, которые предоставляют подобный функционал.

Пример использования [RichText](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX) для этой задачи можно посмотреть [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/861957/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-richtextfx#862718).